# Can I use an Apple Developer Certificate as SSL Server Certificate

Tags: ios, pki

Can we use Apple PKI certificates for SSL, mail and wifi 509x loging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

1. The key usage is only set to ‘Digital Signature’ and marked as critical, but for a TLS/SSL server cert you want ‘Digital Signature’ and ’Key Encipherment’.
2. There is no ‘Subject alternative names’ extension to specify which server address the certificate is for. The subject common name which some clients use as a fallback is also not a valid server address.

It is possible to write a client that replaces the normal certificate validation algorithm, but I interpret your question to not be about that case.